# modifying html in a way to such that left key should take to next url

Tags: javascript, html

I have design a webpage that is .htm ,  in which below is the tag

```
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>rgon.ps.ads.sink.ce=<a href="http://lo6.fm.absgrp.net:330/rgonem/summary.htm?sortby=to&route_filterin=@rgon.ps.ds.sink.ice@">@argon.ps.ads.sink.ce@</a></span></p>
```

now the ouput of above .htm file is

```
rgon.ps.ds.sink.ice=@rgon.ps.ds.sink.ce@
```

now i want to modify it in such a way such that rite now if we click on the value that is in the right hand side then it takes away to the new url now i want to modify it such that i want to remove the value of the right hand side `@rgon.ps.ds.sink.ce@` and the value on the left hand side that is  `rgon.ps.ds.sink.ice` should be there and it should takes me to the direct url itself , want to remove completely the right hand side `@rgon.ps.ds.sink.ce@`value

Folks please is there any Javascript tag or code function that can help me in this situation.

Comment: the output of the HTML is roughly: `rgon.ps.ads.sink.ce=@argon.ps.ads.sink.ce@` except you changed some things somehow to become the output you say or you have to fix some typos! Back to your question. Can we say you want the `<span>` to become the link? How do you want to modify? any scripting language or just change the HTML?

Comment: I want to remove the right hand part and only left hand part should be there which act as url  itself

Comment: How do you want to modify? On the client side with javascript or jQuery? Or can you modify it on the server with whatever is running on the server PHP, ASP, TWIG ?

Comment: On the client side please,  Please advise

Comment: Simple java script will work

Comment: Have you tried any javascript? You might also want to add the javascript tag to your question?

Comment: I have added the Javascript  tag please,  please what will be the Javascript to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this, it will make your left side value to be clickable to go to next url:

```
    <p class=MsoNormal>
        <span style='font-family:"Courier New"'>
            <a href="http://lo6.fm.absgrp.net:330/rgonem/summary.htm?sortby=to&route_filterin=@rgon.ps.ds.sink.ice@">
                rgon.ps.ads.sink.ce
            </a>
        </span>
    </p>
```